# Rendering HTML tables in an MVC framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, struts2

I've been using *Struts2* as my MVC framework as part of building a J2EE-based web application.

Part of the application is to display reports (HTML tables) that are mainly thousands of rows and tens of columns in size. I have implemented pagination to make the report readable etc...

The way the reporting system works today is as follows: The entire data is prepared in an OOP approach and placed on the ValueStack. A corresponding JSP would read the data of the valueStack and use JSTL to draw the HTML code.

I'm in the process of revamping the code and i would like to revisit this logic to conform with the best practices in the industry. The main question here, what are the best practices out there?

Rendering and drawing the report is taking time. Especially on IE-based browsers where the page becomes unresponsive until data is shown (*IE8* support is a must im afraid). So what is the best option?

Is it using *javascript* frameworks such as *jQuery* and move the drawing part to be client-side? Do I know store the entire HTML code on the value stack somehow and display it in 1 shot? 
What's the optimal way in your opinion?

Comment: One best practice is calculating on server only the data of the pagination tab you show. If you show e.g. results 100 to 199 on a page, order your data and get items 100 to 199 only from server and you save the server from calculating so long. Handling less amount of data per view may be better of in efficiency, although you load each page from server.

Comment: Another way to think about it: A solution to render everything and present it is probably the fastest way to present the _whole_ result set. Issue is very few probably want the whole result set. If you can identify what people need and provide appropriate filter methods, people will get what they what faster with much less data being sent. Another consideration is that even if they want to view the whole set (in a browser) responsiveness is key, consider a visible region of 50 records but a json fetch size of 100. Then fetch new sets as the range moves towards the end of the available records.

Comment: There are javascript UI controls that already provide this functionality (seamless scrolling) it is a common feature of modern "data-grids".

Comment: @Quaternion: Seamless scrolling is the future. When you are on desktop, it is extremely pleasant, but when you are on mobile, with your fingers only... the difference in UX is *huge* ! In my last project I've implemented bidirectional infinite scrolling on a calendar (manually, I haven't found anything bidirectional *out-of-the-box*), and the users are still clapping :) BTW, can you post a couple of names of good UI controls with integrated seamless scrolling you have used (or seen) ? Thanks

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll

Comment: The older ng-grid (of which ui-grid is the successor) also has this feature via: scope.$on('ngGridEventScroll', function () {/*append rows to grid*/});

Answer (score 1):

When and how to use pagination is primarily use-case based, and should be evaluated for each case, basing on the number of overall records, the number of records per page, the size of a single record, the main devices used in the ecosystem (prevalently desktop, prevalently mobile, mixed, etc...), network, server and database capabilities, and so on.

But IF you decide to go with pagination (if you have a lot of record, it is the only choice), then the only Best Practice is to load only the data needed for that request.

If you want to see results from 90 to 100 in a resultset of 10.000, it would be awful to load all the 10.000 records in the page; it would be also wrong to load all the 10.000 records serverside, then transmitting only the 10 requested to the client; the filtering must be applied at the lowest possible level, generally the database.

Since you have tagged this Struts2, jQuery and Grid, I strongly suggest you to take a look at the [Struts2-jQuery-Grid-Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag), and its [Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action).

It is new and actively maintained, it only needs a small effort on the initial learning curve.

It is the Struts2 wrapper of the native [jQueryGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5) (you can use the original one, if you want to handle the Javascript on your own).

There are over 200 questions here on SO on [jQGrid pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jqgrid%20pagination%20is%3Aquestion), good read.